# Confusion about the primary decomposition theorem in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial, primary-decomposition

I am currently studying the Jordan canonical form which uses the primary decomposition.

I have seen the generalised eigenspace decomposition and I know that the algebraic multiplicity which appears in the characteristic polynomial is equal to the dimension of the generalised eigenspace. I thought this decomposition is related to the primary decomposition.

So my question is: why do we use the minimal polynomial instead of the characteristic polynomial in the primary decomposition? Or is there a way to prove the Jordan canonical form theorem without using primary decomposition?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not necessary to use the primary decomposition to prove the existence of Jordan canonical form, but the primary decomposition makes for a nice intermediate step

Comment: Are you using the textbook by Hoffman and Kunze?

Comment: No I just have my lecture notes, in which primary decomposition is used to prove the existence of Jordan canonical form

Comment: I just don’t get the intuition behind why minimal polynomial is used here

Comment: There are different useful ways that the minimal polynomial can be interpreted in the context of the primary decomposition and Jordan form, but both of these **can** be derived using the characteristic polynomial instead. As for why your professor chose to use the minimal polynomial rather than the characteristic polynomial, I'm not a mind reader.

Comment: All materials about primary decomposition I could find online use minimal polynomial. Could you elaborate how to interpret it and how to derive it using characteristic polynomial? Thanks!

Comment: If I find the time I will, but this kind of thing takes some time to write up. The only relevant property of the minimal polynomial $\mu(x)$  of $A$ (for the purposes of the primary decomposition) is that $\mu(A) = 0$, the characteristic polynomial $\chi(x)$ also satisfies $\chi(A) = 0$ so it can be used in essentially the same way.

Comment: A bit about interpretation: in the minimal polynomial $\mu(x)=(x - \lambda_1)^{r_1}\cdots (x - \lambda_k)^{r_k}$, each $r_j$ is the size of the largest Jordan block associated with $\lambda_j$; notably this means that a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if every $r_j$ is equal to $1$. For the primary decomposition, the kernels (aka nullspaces) $\ker[(A - \lambda_j I)^1], \dots, \ker[(A - \lambda_j I)^{r_j}]$ are a series of nested subspaces with $\ker[(A - \lambda_j I)]$ equal to the eigenspace associated with $\lambda_j$ and $\ker[(A - \lambda_jI)^{r_j}]$ the entire generalized eigenspace.

Comment: If $s_j$ is the exponent of $(A - \lambda_j)$ in the characteristic polynomial and $n$ is the size of the matrix $A$, then 
$$
\ker(A - \lambda_j I )^{r_j} = \ker(A - \lambda_j I )^{s_j} = \ker(A - \lambda_j I )^{n},
$$
and all of these are necessarily equal to the general eigenspace associated with $\lambda_j$. Perhaps a bit more in detail, $\ker(A - \lambda_j I)^m$ will always equal the entire generalized eigenspace when $m \geq r_j$, and we can always guarantee that $r_j \leq s_j \leq n$.

Comment: I think I get it now. Thanks a lot!